# How to get the memory size of the actual type of a given variant?

Tags: delphi, variant

Consider the following code:

```
procedure Test;
var
  IntGenuine: UInt64;
  IntVariant: Variant;

begin
  IntGenuine := 0;
  IntVariant := UInt64(0); // The type of the variant is UInt64 now

  WriteLn('Size of IntGenuine = ', SizeOf(IntGenuine)); // Output: 8
  WriteLn('Size of IntVariant = ', SizeOf(IntVariant)); // Output: 24
end;
```

I know that the statement `SizeOf(IntVariant)` is equivalent to `SizeOf(Variant)`. It gets the size of type `Variant`, not the size of the actual type of the variant (`UInt64` in this case).

How to get the memory size of the actual type of a given variant?

Comment: This sounds like a case where it may be helpful for you to describe what you are trying to do and the context you need this information for.  There may be a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do...

Comment: I'm making a simple program that test the effect of endianness in unsigned integer types (16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit). I want to represent every octet (8-bit) or hextet (16-bit) in memory in hexadecimal representation. The number of digits to be passed to `IntToHex` should depend on the size of a given integer type, that is `SizeOf(UIntValue) * 8`.

Comment: @David - Because overloading means I have to create three functions. It is obvious now that the reason is my laziness. :-)

Comment: Sounds like variant is not what you need

Comment: @David - Yes, I wrongly described the reason because a hurry. The length of hex digits is not related to the size of a given integer type. After I carefully look again to my source code, the actual reason is ... there's a code that display the number of bits in a given integer type. I calculate the number of bits as `SizeOf(UIntValue) * 8`.

Comment: Variant still seems wrong to me.

Comment: @David - Agreed. I revert my code to the previous state. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function something like this :

```
Program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Variants, SysUtils;

function GetVarTypeSize(AVarType : TVarType; var isArray : boolean) : integer;
begin

  isArray := AVarType <> (AVarType and VarTypeMask);    

  case AVarType and VarTypeMask of
    varSmallInt: result := SizeOf(SmallInt);
    varInteger:  result := SizeOf(Integer);
    varSingle:   result := SizeOf(Single);
    varDouble:   result := SizeOf(Double);
    varCurrency: result := SizeOf(Currency);
    varDate:     result := SizeOf(TDateTime);
    varOleStr:   result := SizeOf(PWideChar);
    varDispatch: result := SizeOf(Pointer);
    varError:    result := SizeOf(HRESULT);
    varBoolean:  result := SizeOf(WordBool);
    varUnknown:  result := SizeOf(Pointer);
    varShortInt: result := SizeOf(ShortInt);
    varByte:     result := SizeOf(Byte);
    varWord:     result := SizeOf(Word);
    varLongWord: result := SizeOf(LongWord);
    varInt64:    result := SizeOf(Int64);
    varUInt64:   result := SizeOf(UInt64);
    varString:   result := SizeOf(Pointer);
    varAny:      result := SizeOf(Pointer);
    varArray:    result := SizeOf(PVarArray);
    varByRef:    result := SizeOf(Pointer);
    varUString:  result := SizeOf(Pointer);
    varRecord:   result := SizeOf(TVarRecord);
  else
    result := -1;  //unknown
  end;
end;

var
  v : Variant;
  b : boolean;
begin
  v := 3.141592654;   // double
  Write(GetVarTypeSize(VarType(v), b));
  if b then WriteLn(' : Is array') else WriteLn;

  v := 3;             // byte
  Write(GetVarTypeSize(VarType(v), b));
  if b then WriteLn(' : Is array') else WriteLn;

  v := integer(3);    // integer
  Write(GetVarTypeSize(VarType(v), b));
  if b then WriteLn(' : Is array') else WriteLn;

  v := Now;           // DateTime
  Write(GetVarTypeSize(VarType(v), b));
  if b then WriteLn(' : Is array') else WriteLn;

  v := VarArrayCreate([0,9], varDouble);   //array ! careful
  Write(GetVarTypeSize(VarType(v), b));
  if b then WriteLn(' : Is array') else WriteLn;

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Here `VarTypeMask` will mask the bit that defines a variant array.  Masking it will tell you the type of the array elements if the base variant is an array type.

You can read more [in the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types).

Comment: The value would be wrong for embedded strings, for instance, and also it won't handle varByRef values (you would need to call it recursively). I still don't get what this information is useful for.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Indeed, there are definitely corner cases that this doesn't handle.  And agreed, I also feel OP is probably on the wrong track trying to solve a problem this way... I don't think this would be part of any solution I would ever use.

Answer (score 2):

If your variable is a `variant`, it will use (at least) 16 bytes under Win32, and 24 bytes under Win64, *whatever value is stored*.

The *memory size of this variable* would always be the one of the `variant` structure, which is defined as `TVarData` in `System.pas`.

Defining:

```
var
  IntVariant: Variant;
```

is in fact the same as defining:

```
var
  IntVariant: TVarData;
```

With some initialization/finalization magic:

```
var
  IntVariant: TVarData;
begin
  IntVariant.VType := varEmpty;
  try
    ...
  finally
    VarClear(variant(IntVariant));
  end;
end;
```

If you store nothing (`varEmpty` or `varNull`), it would still use 16/24 bytes. If you store a `boolean`, it would still use 16/24 bytes. If it stores some `string`, you would have to add the heap-allocated stored text value to the 16/24 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Variants are stored in a record of type `TVarData` behind the scenes.

[System.TVarData Record](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_TVarData.html):

```
PVarData = ^TVarData;
TVarData = packed record
  case Integer of
    0: (VType: TVarType;
        case Integer of
          0: (Reserved1: Word;
              case Integer of
                0: (Reserved2, Reserved3: Word;
                    case Integer of
                      varSmallInt: (VSmallInt: SmallInt);
                      varInteger:  (VInteger: Integer);
                      varSingle:   (VSingle: Single);
                      varDouble:   (VDouble: Double);
                      varCurrency: (VCurrency: Currency);
                      varDate:     (VDate: TDateTime);
                      varOleStr:   (VOleStr: PWideChar);
                      varDispatch: (VDispatch: Pointer);
                      varError:    (VError: HRESULT);
                      varBoolean:  (VBoolean: WordBool);
                      varUnknown:  (VUnknown: Pointer);
                      varShortInt: (VShortInt: ShortInt);
                      varByte:     (VByte: Byte);
                      varWord:     (VWord: Word);
                      varLongWord: (VLongWord: LongWord);
                      varInt64:    (VInt64: Int64);
                      varUInt64:   (VUInt64: UInt64);
                      varString:   (VString: Pointer);
                      varAny:      (VAny: Pointer);
                      varArray:    (VArray: PVarArray);
                      varByRef:    (VPointer: Pointer);
                      varUString:  (VUString: Pointer);
                      varRecord:   (VRecord: TVarRecord);
                      //$ffff:     (VLargest: TLargestVarData);
                   );
                1: (VLongs: array[0..{$IFDEF CPUX64}4{$ELSE}2{$ENDIF}] of LongInt);
             );
          2: (VWords: array [0..{$IFDEF CPUX64}10{$ELSE}6{$ENDIF}] of Word);
          3: (VBytes: array [0..{$IFDEF CPUX64}21{$ELSE}13{$ENDIF}] of Byte);
        );
    1: (RawData: array [0..{$IFDEF CPUX64}5{$ELSE}3{$ENDIF}] of LongInt);
end;
```

The information you are looking for can be obtained casting the `Variant` variable to this type:

```
var
  varData: TVarData;
  intVariant: Variant;
  size: Integer;
begin
  intVariant := UInt64(10);
  varData := TVarData(IntVariant);

  case varData.VType of
    varUInt64: size := SizeOf(varData.VUInt64);
    varInteger: size := SizeOf(varData.VInteger);
  . . .
  end;
end;
```

... but the above is not the usual way to do so:

```
var
  intVariant: Variant;
  size: Integer;
  vType: Integer;
begin     
  vType := VarType(intVariant) and VarTypeMask;
  case vType of
    varUInt64: size := SizeOf(UInt64);
    varInteger: size := SizeOf(Integer);
    . . .
  end;
end;
```